# LibGDX: open android camera

Tags: android, libgdx, camera

I need help, I can't find a solution to open camera device in my libgdx app. I'm developing it only in Android for now but I have this issue.
I need only to open the preview view, no snap picture o make video... I followed this example but I found this unhelpful.

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Integrating-libgdx-and-the-device-camera

Have you other resource to do that?

Thanks

Comment: what do u mean by this issue? can you please explain what issuse exactly you are facing

Comment: I think that it is very clear... use the camera preview inside my app

Comment: The link that you posted seems to be a pretty good resource on how to accomplish this start to finish. Just remember that the idea with anything platform specific in libgdx is that you create an interface to the platform specific functionality and inject it into your libgdx app. The link you posted is doing exactly that.